# If $f(x) =\left(\frac{2x^4y-5x^2y^2+y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$, how to choose $\delta$ so that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies |f(x,y)|<0.01\,$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) = \left(\frac{2x^4y-5x^2y^2+y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$ when $x, y\neq0$ and $f(x) = 0, when\space x, y = 0$

find a $\delta > 0$, such that $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| < 0.01$, whenever $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}<\delta$

I tried to solve it by using polar co-ordinates but the problem has higher order terms which is making it difficult to find any pattern or common terms to reduce it. I don't want complete solution please give me a direction and I will try to work from there. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was about to try something similar but I was too tired after trying to use polar co-ordinates for so long. I will solve it now :)

Comment: @symplectomorphic Is this necessarily true? What if $y$ is negative? (the first step, I mean)

Comment: @user3626393 If you try $f(x,tx)$ for a fixed $t$ not $0$, you find that $f(x,tx)\to -5t^2/(1+t^2)^2 \not =0$ as $x\to 0$. Are you sure that you have $-5x^2y^2$, or it is $-5x^2y^3$ or $-5x^3y^2$ ?

Comment: @Kelenner Now that I think about it such a delta may not be possible, yeah the question is taken verbatim from civil services examination of India. So I doubt the question is wrong.

Comment: @user3626393 Compute $f(x,x)$.

Comment: @Kelenner I could share the link of paper with you if you want, $f(x,x) = (3x-5)/4$

Comment: @Kelenner [link]https://unsee.cc/mudapise/

Comment: @user3626393 No, I have the same result as you have, and the conclusion is that your function does not go to $0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. There is probably a misprint in the paper.

Comment: @Kelenner I guess you are correct but perhaps it was a trick question and we were to show that such a $\delta$ does not exist.

Comment: Though the question has been quite adequately answered already, I am somewhat curious where you ran into trouble with polar coordinates. 
$$\begin{align}f(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta) &= \frac{2r^5\cos^4\theta\sin \theta - 5r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta + r^5\sin^5\theta}{r^4}\\
&=r(5r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta + \sin^5\theta) - 5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\end{align}$$

Letting $r \to 0+$ sends the first term to $0$, but leaves the second term untouched. Since the second term is not always $0$, $f$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: @πr8: whoops, yes.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I was trying to reduce the expression using polar co-ordinates, and since question was framed to solve for $\delta$ I did not check for continuity at that time

Comment: "continuous at 0" was just a shorthand for your problem. You are trying to find a particular $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon = 0.01$ in proving that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = f(0,0)$, which is continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$. But since as $r \to 0, f(r,\theta) \to -5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta \ne 0$, And $|5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta| > 0.01$ for many values of $\theta$, this is obviously impossible.