# How to find delta, for a given epsilon?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, real-numbers

[image]

Problem that I am facing:

So naturally I decided to shift to the polar co-ordinates, however when I try to simplify the expression remains very complicated and despite using the fact that sin and cos belong to [-1,1] I cannot get any conclusive bound.

Thanks

Comment: Same question: [If $f(x) =\left(\frac{2x^4y-5x^2y^2+y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$, how to choose $\delta$ so that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies |f(x,y)|<0.01\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240630/145141)

Comment: That question does not have an answer.

Comment: Is this because when r-> 0, the function can never be less than 0.01?

Comment: Sure it can be less than 0.01, but not on every path approaching $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yea sorry, I meant that there exists a path where it can never be less than 0.01.

Comment: For example, try the path $y=x$. On that path, as $x$ approaches zero, there is a limit, but the limit is not zero.

Comment: Bottom line: As stated, the problem is wrong. Perhaps a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commenters in this question and the linked question have stated, it is impossible to solve this problem.  Here is a proof of the negation.

You are asked to show that
$$\exists \delta > 0,\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,\ 0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta \implies |f(x,y)| < 0.01$$
I will show that
$$ \forall \delta > 0,\exists (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ 0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta \wedge |f(x,y)| \geq 0.01
$$

Let $\delta > 0$ be given.

Setting $y=x$ in the function and taking the limit as $x\to 0$ gives
$$
    \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x^5 - 5 x^4 + x^5}{4x^4} = - \frac{5}{4}
$$
This means there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$0 < |x| < \delta_1 \implies f(x,x) < -1$.  Set $x = y = \min\left\{\frac{\delta}{2},\frac{\delta_1}{2}\right\}$.  Then $0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$ and $|x|< \delta_1$ are both satisfied.  It follows from the second inequality that $|f(x,y)| \geq 1 > 0.01$.